# Is there any way to request a single react component from an endpoint?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, typescript, testing

Basically, What I want to achieve is to model a react component as an endpoint so that I can mount it for example in an html separately. I specifically want to mimic Cypress.mount() command but without having to depend on the client side code. Is this possible and how would one do it?

Comment: You need to provide more detail on your exact use case, what you've tried, and what you're trying to accomplish. As it stands, it feels like you're just describing SSR.

Comment: If this is the expected use for a component then expose initialization script or function when bundling the app. It's unknown what's your case and what would be the best way to solve it